# How can I remove persistence after making changes?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, live-usb, persistence

I wanted to disable one of my graphic cards from starting on boot so i created a Xubuntu 18.04 LTS with UNetbootin with persistance. Then I added `radeon.modeset=0` to the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  through `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

That did the trick but now I want to remove persistance but keep this change. How do I do that?

If there's an alternate way to permenantly add the line or disable the graphic card from changing on a non-persistent Live USB, that would would do too.

Also, I want this Live USB on a multi boot USB (I'm using Ventoy) so not sure how I can make the changes if it requires to first make persistance.

Comment: Unetbootin: Remove the boot option `persistent` in the same way as you added `radeon.modeset=0` (and keep `radeon.modeset=0`) from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. -- I don't know the details of Ventoy.

Comment: Edit the line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that starts with `linux`.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? A little bit more detail on the steps would be nice. Edit ^ and add what exactly to which line?

Comment: If you need more help, please edit your original question to display the line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that starts with `linux`, and I can describe how to change it. You may need to boot with the boot optiion `toram` to be allowed to edit that file (and you can add it temporarily at boot (press 'e' at the grub menu)).

Comment: Once I open grub, what then?

Comment: Please edit your original question to display the line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that starts with `linux`.

Comment: Just did ^^^^^^^

Comment: Welcome to the chat room :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115881/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jjrussel).

Comment: If you intend on booting 18.04 using UNetbootin in BIOS mode edit `/syslinux.cfg`. If you intend on booting in UEFI mode edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. adding `radeon.modeset=0`. Neither of these items depend on using persistent install. The work should be done from a separate OS, either Windows or Linux, not from the running Persistent USB.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron "If you intend on booting 18.04 using UNetbootin in BIOS mode edit /syslinux.cfg" could you help me out with instructions on how to do this? You say "Neither of these items depend on using persistent install". My Windows is not starting and I'm stuck in a boot loop. The Xubuntu live USB I have is currently not persistent. Can I make the changes on it in WinPE (bootable Windows for repairs) or Xubuntu booted from another Live USB?

Comment: Instructions for UNetbootin below, instructions for Rufus and mkusb given on your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding `radeon.modeset=0` to UNetbootin Non-Persistent Install

- If booting BIOS mode boot the UNetbootin USB and press Tab, type a space then `toram`.
- Once booted and stable, unplug and replug the USB.
- Edit `/cdrom/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, adding `radeon.modeset=0` after quiet splash in the first menuentry
- Then Edit `/cdrom/syslinux.cfg`, adding `radeon.modeset=0` after quiet splash in the first menu item.

This change will be permanent.

If you are booting in UEFI mode press `e` at the boot menu and add `toram` after `quiet splash`.

Once booted edit grub.cfg and syslinux.cfg as above.

You can also edit the boot files running from another Live USB or desktop. Booted from another Live USB the paths are `/media/xubuntu/USBNAME/syslinux.cfg` and `/media/xubuntu/USBNAME/boot/grub/grub.cfg` where `USBNAME` is the name of the USB. In this case `cdrom` is not on the path.

Comment: Pressing `shift` doesn't do anything. But it does when I created the USB with mkusb. I just recreated xubuntu again using UNetbootin because the mkusb instructions you posted on my other question wasn't working so I thought I give this a try. Any pointers?

Comment: If shift is not working, you may be booting UEFI mode. Try the method for UEFI above.

Comment: E just resets the countdown. Do you mean 'tab'? https://bit.ly/38yzCYX. This is when I hit tab... https://imgur.com/QlC8lNh. Also, am I booting from the USB I'm doing the work on?

Comment: Also what difference is it going to make booting from ram? I tried editing the file on another USB (not the one I booted from) and I was not able to do so. Wouldn't this technically be the sane thing?

Comment: @JJrussel: `e` works for UEFI mode, Tab works for BIOS mode in UNetbootin. You are correct, (Shift works with other installers). Type a space and toram after quiet splash.

Comment: Both methods should work as long as you are editing syslinux.cfg as root. Open nautilus with `sudo -H nautilus`,  (with a capital H).

Comment: @JJrussel: Use `sudo -H nautilus` if you are booting from Ubuntu to edit `grub.cfg` and `syslinux.cfg`, If booting using Xubuntu use `sudo -H thunar`. This method only works with a Unetbootin or Rufus USB.

Comment: However with Rufus the file to edit for BIOS boot is `/isolinux/txt.cfg`

Comment: OK. This worked!! Thank your sooooo much!! 

Comment: Problem...even though I was able to save `radeon.modeset=0` in txt.cfg, and confirm it by pressing `tab` during the countdown loading screen and see it there, it did not work disabling the graphic card

Comment: So basically, I added `radeon.modeset=0` in `txt.cfg`, `syslinux.cfg` and, for good measure, `grub.cfg`. Yet I see no effect because the computer is still hanging. This is Xubuntu 20.04 LTS live USB (non-persistent) created with UNetbootin. Thoughts?

Comment: To tell the truth I have never heard of `radeon.modeset=0` before you mentioned it. I think most people just use `nomodeset` to boot is safe graphics mode. Perhaps try that and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Didn't work. ALTHOUGH, I could move the cursor this time, but everything else is frozen. Normally the cursor freezes too.